# is it possible to create persistent disk smaller than snapshot size

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a disk size of 2TB. Only 300GB used. Took the snapshot and snapshot size shows 2TB.

When I try to create a disk of 1TB from the snapshot it throws and error "Disk size cannot be smaller than the snapshot size (2,048 GB)"

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

When a snapshot is created it uploads all physical blocks of your disk, which includes control data structures used by the file system you used to format the disk, e.g. ext4 inodes. When you restore the disk, all those bytes must be copied back to the disk at the exact same position as they were before. This is the reason you can't shrink the disk to a smaller size, it would be equivalent to physically removing half of your hard disk for example.

If you want your files on a smaller disk, you would need to download the snapshot to a 2TB disk, attach a smaller disk to the same VM and copy over the data.

Hope it helps,
Fabricio.

Comment: You'd probably have to copy the boot sector too if this is a root disk.

Answer (score 0):

By taking snapshot, GCP takes the data of the disk & it happens incrementally.
And it wouldn't allow us to move the snapshot to create a lower sized disk, because it has metadata check of the size it stored for source-instance, rather than filled-data size comparison. hence, it will simply abort the operation of creating lower sized disk.

But i still don't understand how the snapshot became 2TB of 1TB disk.
Possibility that i can think of is: you had 2TB disk when the snapshot is taken & later on you/someone might have shrunk the disk to 1TB. This is pure guess.
I don't have any logical reasons about how the snapshot has twice size.

Comment: I suspect the snapshot is a diff to the base OS image, which will have some of the same files in the same space that aren't counted.